# JavaScript ...args not supported in iOS 9? :: JavaScript + Ionic + AngularJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, arguments, ionic-framework

I am playing around in Ionic and noticed that when I tried building an app on iOS 9 where I used `...args` in my function arguments, I would get a white screen in Ionic.

The app would work OK in browser, emulator and device would show white screen. Simply changing `...args` to args and customising my function to cope with this change would fix that.

So my question is, are `...args` not supported in iOS 9? If not, is there a resource where I can see which functions are allowed and which are not?

Oftentimes I work hard only to find out when compiling that what I see in browser is not quite working on the real device (another example are arrow functions from ECMAScript 6, exactly the same issue, fix would be to change from `() => {}` to `function () {}` )

Or is it just me doing something wrong in Ionic/Angular/JavaScript? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rest parameters are [not supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=rest-parameters) in iOS Safari 9. Check this [reference](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-rest_parameters) to see the ES6 compatibility table.

Comment: Thanks man! I actually found the second link but there isn't much in the iOS9 column so I wasn't sure. Thanks.

Comment: Also, do you know any nifty solution to work around this issue?

Comment: Instead of using rest parameters just do the traditional way `function f(foo, bar) { var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, f.length); console.log(args); } f('foo','bar','baz');`